# SQL Injection vs. Microsoft Data Access Application Block SQL helper class

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0, sql-injection

I am using Microsoft helper class (http://www.sharpdeveloper.net/source/SqlHelper-Source-Code-cs.html)

I am using this method to insert data in table:

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO table(col1, col2) Values(@val1, @val2)";
SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
param[0] = new SqlParameter("@val1", "abc");
param[1] = new SqlParameter("@val2", 123);
int rows = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(DataAccess.ConnectionString, CommandType.Text, query, param);
```

I want to know that is there any security risk using this way i.e SQL injection etc?

Comment: To make it even better, use the `const` keyword and ditch the `@`, so you would have `const string query = "INSERT INTO table(col1, col2) Values(@val1, @val2)";`

Comment: So, you're using .NET 2.0?

Comment: yes. on some sites i am using .net 4.0 also.

Answer (score 3):

The code you've posted is fine and uses parameters for all variable components of your SQL command, so it is immune from SQL injection attacks.